# Base file naming conventions

Tags: naming-conventions, filesystems

I have a few web pages that all perform various functions for one main piece of functionality or "tool".

Instead of having one massive page where I do the various functions based on a "mode" query parameter (?mode=edit, new, view, etc.) I want to break up the pages so debugging won't be such a nightmare since the code is long and complex.

So what I'm going to do is name the pages as follows:

tool.asp
tool-edit.asp
tool-new.asp
tool-view.asp

Are there any issues when using a "-" in a base file name?

Any other suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It should work just fine.  My only suggestion is to switch off of classic ASP to ASP.NET. :)